# C++ template specialization all types except one

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I need a method(C++ 11) that is called for all types except one.

```
template<typename T>
void method(T& value)
{
...
}

template<>
void method(std::string& value)
{
...
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this? If not, is there other alternatives than using typeid at runtime?

Comment: How is that any different from having a specialization just for one type?

Comment: What's wrong with the solution you've shown?

Comment: Did googling "template specializarion" not give you the answer you need? If not, why? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: You already did it. For alltypes except `string`, the main template will be used.

Comment: If its for that *one* type, why aren't you just [using an overload](http://ideone.com/9aN4KM)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need template specialization. And neither SFINAE (`enable_if`). When you get caught up in template functions it's easy to forget that **functions can overload**. Just create a non-templated overload and that will be preferred when passing an argument of that **exact type** (a better solution is presented in the linked article):

```
template<typename T>
void method(T& value)
{
  // ...
}

void method(std::string& value)
{
  // ...
}
```

---

I strongly recommend reading this article [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) by Herb Sutter.

> Moral #1: If you want to customize a function base template and want
> that customization to participate in overload resolution (or, to
> always be used in the case of exact match), **make it a plain old
> function, not a specialization**. And, if you do provide overloads,
> avoid also providing specializations.

But you fall in the Moral #2:

> But what if you're the one who's writing, not just using, a function
> template? Can you do better and avoid this (and other) problem(s) up
> front, for yourself and for your users? Indeed you can:
>
> Moral #2: If you're writing a function base template, **prefer to
> write it as a single function template that should never be
> specialized or overloaded**, and then implement the function template
> entirely as a simple handoff to a class template containing a static
> function with the same signature. Everyone can specialize that -- both
> fully and partially, and without affecting the results of overload
> resolution.

The whole explanation is in the article.

Comment: well, plain overloading is better than specialization, if one wants to overload function, not to remove it. But sometimes using plain overloading is insufficient (handling groups of types, value categories, implicitly-convertible types and so on)

Comment: @AndreiR. if you want to remove it then you can just `= delete`. If you need groups of types etc., then yes, it is insufficient.

Comment: Keep in mind, overloading can cause issues when trying to specialize for types that have the same decay type. It is not possible to not cause ambiguity when trying to specialize for char*, const char*, char[], const char[], string literal, std::string and const std::string

Comment: For me, "exact type" version should be put before template version.

Answer (score 7):

there are several ways to do this, so you can use most convenient one:

```
// way 1
template<typename T, 
         typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value>::type* = nullptr>
// way 2
void method(T& value)
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T,std::string>::value,"std::string is not accepted");
    ...
}

// way 3
template <>
void method<std::string>(std::string&) = delete;
```

As for me, I find 3 to be the most convenient one for filtering out specific type, and 1 for filtering out some subset of types

Comment: With gcc-6 and cmcstl2 you can also use concepts. That is much more convenient than using `enable_if`s

Comment: @Maikel, yep, I know, but it would also be verbose: `requires !std::is_same<T,std::string>::value`

Comment: If we want to ignore modifiers like const, volatile, way 3 needs a bunch of deletes, while way 1 and 2 just require a few more calls to remove the modifiers statistically.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic template specialization, look at code sample below.

Code sample (based on your code):

```
template<typename T>
void method(T& value) {
    //
}

template<>
void method<std::string>(std::string& value) {
    //
}
```

This means, when you call method with std::string parameter the second (specialized) method will be called. Otherwise if you do not want to have the second function, then you will have to use c++ type traits (answered in the other answer).